# Stop processing PHP file completely

Tags: php

I need to be able to completely stop processing a file/page if a certain condition exists, for examaple:

```
<?php
    if ($conditions == "true") {
        echo "Condition is true";
    }
        else {
        echo "Condition is not true";
        //Command here to completely stop processing all the page;
    }
?>

<?php
    //nothing else should run here if the aboe condition is not true
?>

<?php
    //or this part
?>
```

So basically, if the condition in the first if else is false, no further processing is done, including ignoring the following two  parts.

Can this be done?

If confused with die() and exit as from what I have read, it will only stop the first part but continue to run the second and third parts within the

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php ... terminate the script ...

Comment: @Devon THanks, and that will not process any more of the page?

Comment: Correct. Either of those two will completely stop the rest of the script from running.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you all very much, that is now clear for me.